# String introducida mediante EditText se borra al salir de la Actividad

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que presionas un botón, abre un `AlertDialog` e introduces en un `EditText` un texto, el cual será ingresado en el mismo botón en el que se ha presionado.

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que al salir de la Actividad y volver a entrar, el texto que ingresé en el botón no aparece, se ha borrado.

Quisiera saber cómo mantener el String que se ha introducido.

Éste es mi código:

```
    package thirdline.schooltools;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class FirstTrimesterActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonsubject1;
    EditText edittextsubject1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_trimester);


    buttonsubject1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsubject1);

    buttonsubject1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstTrimesterActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Subject:");

            final EditText edittextsubject1=new EditText(FirstTrimesterActivity.this);

            builder.setView(edittextsubject1);


                    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            buttonsubject1.setText(edittextsubject1.getText().toString());
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);



            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }





    });


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El texto se borra porque no se almacena en ninguna parte, Usa SharedPreferences

Mediante **[getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getSharedPreferences())** podrias guardar el valor dentro de tu EditText, usando los siguientes metodos:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValuePreference(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("valorEditText", text);
    editor.commit();
}



public String getValuePreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("valorEditText", "");
}
```

Al aceptar tu Dialogo podrías guardar el valor:

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            buttonsubject1.setText(edittextsubject1.getText().toString());

                       //GUARDA VALOR EN PREFERENCIA.
                       saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), edittextsubject1.getText().toString());


                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
```

y al cargar nuevamente tu EditText, obtenerlo de preferencias:

```
...
final EditText edittextsubject1=new EditText(FirstTrimesterActivity.this);
//OBTIENE VALOR EN PREFERENCIA Y SE AGREGA AL EDITTEXT.
edittextsubject1.setText(getValuePreference(getApplicationContext());
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Se supone que cuando sales de la `activity`, esta se destruye y cuando vuelves, la `activity` arma la vista completamente denuevo, por eso es que se borra tu texto que ingresaste.

Para completar la respuesta de @Elanasys, en el evento `onCreate()` de tu `activity` debes llamar a sus `SharedPreferences` y busca el texto que ingresaste

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_trimester);


    buttonsubject1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsubject1);

    //Si es distinto de vacio, quiere decir que ya habia una antes se le da el texto al boton
    if(this.getValuePreference(this) != ""){
        buttonsubject1.setText(getValuePreference(this));
    }
    ....
}

private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValuePreference(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("valorEditText", text);
    editor.commit();
}



public String getValuePreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString("valorEditText", "");
}
```